# Using self generated error codes via method

Tags: php, function

I am trying to create a way to generate and deal with my own error codes for a site that I have been contraccted. For this, I need to catch, log and show an error depending on where the error is generated/what it is.

Is what I am trying to do the right way about it? (So far all I have is the base of the errornums array and the check_if_error() function).

```
//errornums array:
        $this->errornums = array(
            000=>'The selected is not a sport<br>Please try again.',                            
            /** 000 represent the deafult value for the switch_sport() function where the sport is not recognised.*/
            111=>'Visitor number exists.',                                                      
            /** 111 represents when a visitor number exists.*/
            222=>'',                                                                            
            /** 222 represents*/
            333=>'',                                                                            
            /** 333 represents*/
            444=>'',                                                                            
            /** 444 represents*/
            555=>'',                                                                            
            /** 555 represents*/
            666=>'',                                                                            
            /** 666 represents*/
            777=>'',                                                                            
            /** 777 represents*/
            888=>'', 
            /** 888 represents*/
            999=>'Unforseen error has occured.<br>If the problem persists please let us know.'                                                                             
            /** 999 represents a default value for any unkown error.*/
            );

//Check if error function:
private function check_if_error( int $num = 999) {
    if (in_array($num, $this->errornums)) {
        return $this->errornums[$num];
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm not looking for someone to say "This is wrong, don't do it.", what I am asking for is if what I am trying to do is along the general line of whats accepted conventionally.

Comment: Store the error codes in the database? It will allow you to easier update and add error codes in the future (and you won't need to edit the code to edit the meaning of the error code)

Comment: Do you want to create your own [error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)?

Comment: Where I have the array and values stored makes it somewhat easier to edit them in the code rather than the database itself. I did think of that myself but the remote access isn't very stable and the FTP is a lot more reliable to get the files back down to update.

Comment: And yes, that is the thing that I am going for

Comment: I mean this line of your code: `in_array($num, $this->errornums)` doesn't work like you seem to think it does.

Comment: I know it's an array, but if your intention is to check whether a **key** (e.g. `000`, `111`, `222` etc.) exists, you want `array_key_exists()` or `isset($array[$key])`, not `in_array()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you to use static method rather than private method. its easy to access anywhere from your code you dont need to create new instance to call this method every time.

```
static $errornums = array(
        000=>'The selected is not a sport<br>Please try again.',                            
        /** 000 represent the deafult value for the switch_sport() function where the sport is not recognised.*/
        111=>'Visitor number exists.',                                                      
        /** 111 represents when a visitor number exists.*/
        222=>'',                                                                            
        /** 222 represents*/
        333=>'',                                                                            
        /** 333 represents*/
        444=>'',                                                                            
        /** 444 represents*/
        555=>'',                                                                            
        /** 555 represents*/
        666=>'',                                                                            
        /** 666 represents*/
        777=>'',                                                                            
        /** 777 represents*/
        888=>'', 
        /** 888 represents*/
        999=>'Unforseen error has occured.<br>If the problem persists please let us know.'                                                                             
        /** 999 represents a default value for any unkown error.*/
        );

        public static function hasError(int $errorNo = 999)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($errorNo, self::$errornums )) {
                return self::$errornums[$errorNo];
            }
           else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The thing is, I want this method to be internal to the class only, so making it static would make it avaialble outside the class, which is not what I want to do.